# Why a List of DateTime Patterns?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

Why is there more than one DateTime format pattern?  If I execute this code:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// 'd' is standard format string for "short date"
enUS.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d');
```

I am given a string array with the following elements:

```
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
```

I've experimented with parsing short dates and outputting short dates, in all cases only the first pattern at the top of the above list is used.  For example, I tried this:

```
        CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        enUS.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(
           new string[] {  "dd^yyyyy^MM", "yy/MM/dd"  }, 
           'd'
        );
        string date = "04^02014^08";
        DateTime when = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d", enUS); 
        DateTime when2 = DateTime.Parse(date, enUS);
```

The `when` variable correctly captures the date, but the `when2` threw an exception.  If I change the order of the values in the `SetAllDateTimePatterns`, then calling either of the parsing lines causes an exception.  Again, only the first pattern in the list has any effect.

Does anyone know whenever or wherever the other format strings are used?  If they are not used at all, then why does the DateTimeFormatInfo object bother to carry an array of them?

Again, I can only see when and where the first in the list is used.  What is the story here?

Comment: It's used for `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.TryParse()`. It will match the input with all of the formats in there.

Comment: Why the downvotes? There is a great deal of code in the BCL for supporting dates/culture, and it doesn't hurt to ask/understand it. Browsing through the source, it would appear that one pattern is treated as the default (hence it is used when calling `ToString("d")`) but all patterns are available for parsing (like @JeroenVannevel said, although I can't find exactly how this is implemented). Interestingly, the same class also allows date time formats to be set, suggesting that you could define your own format strings.

Comment: Maybe a minor problem that the subject text for the question doesn't specify specifically what the question is about, namely the GetAllDateTimePatterns() method.

Comment: @Jeroen: I had run that test, proving `Parse` and `TryParse` in fact do not use the values in that list.  I have added code to my question to illustrate this.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.setalldatetimepatterns(v=vs.110).aspx) for `SetAllDateTimePatterns` does say "The Parse and TryParse methods do not fully iterate all strings in patterns when parsing the string representation of a date and time." Then it lists several overloads which allow you to specify an array of patterns to use.